# Why is CaseTeamMember not displayed in the Object Manager?

Tags: object-manager

I was just looking at the Object Manager and noticed that the `CaseTeamMember` object is not displayed there. I can see `AccountTeamMember` and `CampaignMember` but not `CaseTeamMember`.

Does anybody know why Salesforce have omitted it from the object manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether this is an answer or not, but I don't think there is a reason that Salesforce has omitted that, it is just not implemented yet.

If you look at recent release notes, Account Team Member is also just recently added in. You can refer to this one: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/administrator-certification-maintenance-winter-20/learn-whats-new-in-winter-20

Comment: Thank you, I think you have a point! Perhaps we will see the Case Team Members in object manager as well. :)